# No module named 'forms' Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to initiate a registration process for my website. I am using Python 3.3.5, and Django 1.6.

I receive an error saying `No module named 'forms'`. I am fairly new to Python/Django.

Here are my files:

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import auth
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from forms import MyRegistrationForm


def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register_success')

    else:
        form = MyRegistrationForm()
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = form

    return render_to_response('register1.html', args)



def register_success(request):
    return render_to_response('register_success.html')
```

Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        # user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

the forms.py is located in the same folder as views.py. I tried from django.forms import MyRegistrationForm but then the error `cannot import name MyRegistrationForm` arises.

Comment: does the folder contains __ init __.py file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you didn't change the default location of `views.py`, then it's likely to be in your application folder. Try something like `from myapp.forms import MyRegistrationForm` where `myapp` is the name of your application

Comment: I will when I get to 15 rep :) (new here)

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks! Is there any reason why (it seems) sometimes `from .forms import ...` works and other times it must be `from myapp.forms import ...`?

Answer (score 11):

if thats an app module, change your 6th line:

```
from forms import MyRegistrationForm
```

to:

```
from .forms import MyRegistrationForm
```

(just add a dot before forms)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. You don't want to hardcode your app name into your app. What if you want to rename your app and have the name of your app in imports everywhere?

Comment: I disagree. What if you have more than one application with the same form name?